# Is there a way to get Google My Business photos on Wordpress with the API or other?

Tags: api

I need to retrieve Google My Business photos on Wordpress, I've read the API but find nothing on it.

Does anyone have a lead on this ?

I am not asking for something ready-made but simply for feedback on someone who has already done this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a very helpful answer, but anything that has an API you can write PHP to talk to that API to get content into your Wordpress. If you can find the API call that does that you want (e.g. gets a URL for photos, or gets the files), then you could post a question for how to integrate that API call into a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: The Google My Business API is documented here: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/overview To use it you need to authenticate and make HTTP requests to that API. WordPress has methods for making HTTP requests that are documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/ If you need more help you will need to ask a more detailed question about the single specific issue you're having. If you don't have development experience and need help for the whole thing, this site is not an appropriate resource. You would be better served by a tutorial or class.